# Jmeter - How to run a load test with login - ajax box - select item - purchase

Tags: ajax, load, jmeter, load-testing

I need to create a test in jmeter where I login to website, search for word in an ajax, display results and after that select one of the results. I created 4 http requests, a GET one for login page, a POST one for logging in, a POST one again for ajax results and another GET one for selecting results. How do I link them? With what type of controller? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "link them"? The scenario you describe seems like they are at least 2 separate user interactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always group these request using a Simple Controller http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller